# Has many association objects count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my application I have model Car which has_many :reservations

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < Activerecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Now i want to pull out from database all cars that have no reservations. How Can I do that?

Edit:
Thank's everyone for help but now I have other problem:
My search method search Cars that not have reservations or not have reservations i proper dates. It looks like this:

```
def self.is_not_reservated(handover_date, return_date)
  without_reservation = where("cars.id NOT IN (?)", Reservation.pluck(:car_id)) 
  with_reservation = joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? 
    AND reservations.return_time >= ?", return_date, handover_date) 
end
```

Now when I try to add this two ActiveRecordRelation object I will have an array but I still want to have an ActiveRecordRelation object...
Is there any way to solve this problem.
Thank's in advance!

My solution:
I don't know that this a good way to do such a thing but it works as expected :)

```
def is_not_reservated(handover_date, return_date)
      without_reservation = where("cars.id NOT IN (?)", Reservation.pluck(:car_id)) 
      with_reservation = joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? 
        AND reservations.return_time >= ?", return_date, handover_date) 
      cars = without_reservation + with_reservation
      where(id: cars.map(&:id))
    end
```

Comment: you can try like this "cars.reservations.size < 1"

Comment: I know about this thing...
But I want to have method which returns me ActiveRelation object.
Car.where("") = ActiveRelation with my cars

Comment: why do you want to have relation and not array?

Comment: Because I will do other operation with this like searching etc. But i found solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it all in the database, even without having to use strings in the query:

```
Car.includes(:reservations).where(reservations: {car_id: nil})

# SELECT * FROM "cars"
# LEFT OUTER JOIN "reservations" ON "reservations"."car_id" = "cars"."id"
# WHERE "reservations"."car_id" IS NULL
```

Comment: This is also very good answer but it generate a bit ugly sql :)

Comment: Beauty lies in the eye of the beholder ;-) I think it is more important that the query does not get longer with the number of records that are in your database.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I've edited my post because know I have other problem. I want to add two ActiveRecordRelation objects and when I done that I have an array but I still want have an ActiveRecordRelation object...

Comment: @MateuszUrbański you have already accepted the answer, so nobody will read your question any more. You should make a new question!

Answer (score 3):

Exactly you need to use the left outer join. It should be something like below,

```
Car.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON reservations.car_id = car.id')
```

For more information please refer this rails documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
Car.where("cars.id NOT IN (?)", Reservation.pluck(:car_id))
```

Comment: Thank's for help but this code is wrong. It generates following sql which not solve the problem.
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (cars.id NOT IN (6))

Comment: `pluck` returns array of ids, how are you getting 6?

Comment: Because I have only one reservation in db which id is 6.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer, it should be `Reservation.pluck(:car_id)` and not `Reservation.pluck(:id)`, check it once again

Comment: Beware that this does not scale well, you have to pull values from the database, make them into Ruby objects, build a query string containing all of the ids and send it back to the database. Let the database to the work!

Comment: IMO. First, `IN` is an expensive query if the data grows over a period of time. Second, `Reservation.pluck(:car_id)` is gonna turn out to an another `ActiveRecord` query. You'll end up running two queries to fetch unreserved cars. So, I don't really think if this will be scalable, as per @p11y's comment.

Comment: It runs two queries, so does `.includes`

Comment: `.includes` has a different purpose altogether, it is for eager loading to prevent n+1 queries.

Comment: `.includes` is _not_ running two queries in case of my solution, its only purpose is to make rails recognize the field name. If you lknow of another way to do this, it's highly welcome! Essentially, my solution is performing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, just as @Mohanraj's answer.

Comment: Btw: "With includes, Active Record ensures that all of the specified associations are loaded using the **minimum possible number of queries.** [...] This would generate a query which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN whereas the joins method would generate one using the INNER JOIN function instead." (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) In this case, Rails knows that it only needs one query ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To further `RSB`'s answer, you may also want to use a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) (basically a class method):

```
#app/models/car.rb
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :unreserved, -> { where("cars.id NOT IN (?)", Reservation.pluck(:car_id)) }
end
```

This will allow you to call `Car.unreserved`

Comment: Be aware that `Reservation.pluck(:car_id)` will make another db query to fetch reservations' car_id.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
Car.joins(:reservations).group("cars.id HAVING count(reservations.id) > 0")
Car.joins(:reservations).group("cars.id").having("count(reservations.id) > ?",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create a method where you run a plain SQL query inside **apps/models/car.rb**:

```
def unreserved_cars
  sql = "Select * from #{self.table_name} where(#{Reservation.table_name}.car_id != id)"
  records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

Or if you need `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects then you can create a scope inside **apps/models/car.rb**:

```
scope :unreserved_cars, -> { where("#{Reservation.table_name}.car_id != id") }
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Car.unreserved_cars
```